# Need to fetch Total Rows Count and Rows count based on Group by in single Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have table  REQUEST

```
REQUESTID`    |    ProductID
----------------------------
1             |       1
2             |       1
3             |       4
4             |       4
5             |       4   `
```

Now  i need output as  within single query

```
  ProductID        |       Count       |     Total
----------------------------------------------------
      1            |         2         |      5
      4            |         3         |      5
```

Basically, i need to calculate  Product  Percentage amongs total  request  how many  percentage  people prefer  particular product. And i need this to be done in single query

Code What I have tried  ::

```
Alter Proc  SP_Get_Product_History_Count
AS

Declare @Tot bigint  

Select  @Tot = COUNT(RequestID) from  Request

Select 
  Pro.ProductName,
  COUNT(Req.RequestID) /@Tot as Count

From 
    Request As  Req
inner join 
    Product As Pro
on  
    Req.ProductID =  Pro.ProductID
 Group by  Pro.ProductName
```

Comment: I can do the above by using a  additional variable, by Select @tot = Count(ProductID) from Request,  then use it.  But i was asked to do by single  query

Comment: But show us the code. The reason I ask what you tried is because SO is not a code generation site.

Comment: I just have added the code what i have tried  so far,  Here  i have used two  Select Queries and i was asked to do this by  single  query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ProductID, total = COUNT(*) OVER()
  FROM dbo.REQUEST
)
SELECT 
  ProductID, 
  COUNT(*), 
  MAX(total), 
  1.0*COUNT(*)/MAX(total)
FROM x
GROUP BY ProductID;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9968a/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select productid,
count(requestid) as [Count],
(select count(requestid) from [Request]) as Total
from [Request]
group by productid
```